# Non-static method STemplate::assign() should not be called statically

Tags: php

I have been trying to do a php pear validation with my validation codes, but all i receive are strict standards error - what's the problem and how can i fix it?

**Strict standards: Non-static method Validate::email() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\chap5\EmailValidation.php on line 5
Strict standards: Non-static method Validate::email() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\chap5\EmailValidation.php on line 11**

Email Validation.php

```
<?php require_once "Validate.php";

$email = '"Doe, John" <johndoe@example.net>'; 
if(Validate::email($email, array('use_rfc822'=> true))){
    echo 'Valid!';
}
else {
    echo $email . " failed."; 
}

if (Validate::email($email, array('check_domain' => true))){
    echo $email . ' is valid and domain exists'; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then function `email` is not defined statically in class `Validate`. So you should not call it statically. Create object of that class and then call the function. Like

```
$validator = new Validation();
$validator->email($email, array('use_rfc822'=> true));  // instead of Validate::email
```

If You can not create object of that class then declare this function as static in that class.
Like

```
public static function email(Arg_same_as_it_is){
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's telling you to express it instead as

```
$validate = new Validate();
$validate->email()
// ...
```